# Getting a unique count of events

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I'm looking for some guidance as I'm struggling to create a script for the fiddle below which will output a high level table of results.

fiddle = http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/c4b136/5

Based on the fiddle, I can work out in a spreadsheet that we have:

- 39 Total Sent (Status = Success)
- 17 Users Opened (Status = opens)
  <unique count of userid and not total opens
- 2 Users Clicked (Status =
  clicked) <unique count of userid and not total clicked
- Meaning 44% of
  users who were sent the email opened, and 5% clicked a link in the
  Email.

I want the output to show as something like this, but when I've tried this myself I've had trouble.
[image]

Comment: You specified both MySQL and Google BigQuery. Please specify only one DBMS. I have removed both tags, please add the actual DBMS your question is about back in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should group only by `start_date` and `campaign_name` and include `DISTINCT` and the `CASE` expressions inside `COUNT()`:

```
select start_date, campaign_name,
       count(distinct case when status = 'Success' then userid end) as Unique_Sent,
       count(distinct case when status = 'opens' then userid end) as Unique_Opened,
       count(distinct case when status = 'clicked' then userid end) as Unique_Clicked,
       round(100 * count(distinct case when status = 'opens' then userid end) /
              count(distinct case when status = 'Success' then userid end)) as `% Opened`,
       round(100 * count(distinct case when status = 'clicked' then userid end) /
             count(distinct case when status = 'Success' then userid end)) as `% Clicked`
from Main
group by start_date, campaign_name;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_5.6&fiddle=eaa939fca6c78e0e848e8dec516e2fe3).

Answer (score 1):

Consider below approach (BigQuery)

```
select campaign_name, success as TotalSent, opens as UniqueOpens, clicked UniqueClicked,
  round(100 * opens / success, 2) as PercentOpened, 
  round(100 * clicked / success, 2) as PercentClicked 
from (
  select * except(start_date, status_date)
  from Main
)
pivot (count(distinct Userid) for lower(status) in ('success', 'opens', 'clicked'))
```

if applied to sample data in your question - output is

[image]